# Restarting nginx on ubuntu fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

Hey I am currently deploying my rails app on an ubuntu 14 server and I when I try to restart nginx it fails.

My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/savoir/shared/tmp/sockets/savoir-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/savoir/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/savoir/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/savoir/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

And if I test the config with this command:

```
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t
```

it tells me that my syntax is ok.

Why does it fail?

EDIT:

The error.log looked like this:

```
2016/02/15 14:17:59 [emerg] 57516#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

With deploy instead of info I get the same error message:

```
2016/02/16 13:20:35 [emerg] 365#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

EDIT2:

I just realized that my conf is placed under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ and is called "savoir" (that's the name of my application). Maybe thats a mistake? I followed this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma).

EDIT3:

Ok, I changed the port in my nginx.conf and it works now:

```
server {
  listen 81 default_server deferred;
}
```

Still can't see my Rails app in the webbrowser though.

EDIT4:

Uninstalled apache2 and changed the port back to 80. Now it works without changing the port.

EDIT5:

I am so close to having my application online but there is one last problem. I found this error in my `puma.access.log`:

```
Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
```

I thought that capistrano adds this on deployment but somehow it didn't:

```
// /config/secrets.yml
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Checking for a secret key with this command `env | grep -E "SECRET_TOKEN|SECRET_KEY_BASE"` doensn't return anything.

I tried to set it manually but that didn't really work. Could someone give me a short explaination how to set it best?

Comment: Any errors showing up in the error.log? Please use `debug` as log level (instead of `info`) and test again. Afterwards, show us the error log :)

Comment: Added the error.log in my main post.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another service already listening on port 80?
try `netstat -na | grep LISTEN` and see if port 80 appears there. if so, use `lsof -i :80` and which process it is

Comment: Thanks, that helped me already a little. I think its the apache2 that uses port 80 as far as I can see. What would be the prefered why to solve this?

Comment: Uninstall Apache if you are not using it. If you are using Apache you can deploy your rails app under Apache as opposed to nginx

Comment: Thanks that works. Now I get following error if I try to reach my application by firefox `An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.`